# Send TCP segment with modified header

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ip

I am designing a TCP server and I need to remove [half-opened connections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne) as fast as possible. Every `n` seconds I try to send some data to clients and when I get an error I stop polling them.

It works just fine except that my clients receive some garbage I send them every `n` seconds and must parse it out.

I would like to send a TCP segment with zero bytes of data. Is it possible to modify TCP segment header and send some kind of fake `SYN` or `ACK` segment with no data?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EdHeal thak you for your comment. I am trying to detect half-opened connections on the server side in order to remove dead client sockets from the polling routine (checking if some data arrived to them). So I want to send keepalive packets with no data to clients to see if they are still conencted.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: @EdHeal This is the problem because the server wastes processor time polling dead sockets which will never have incoming data.

Comment: @EdHeal and the problem will obviously grow as snowball as new clients connect and disconnect.

Comment: You have a problem with the other end with computers crashing and/or routers and/or network. In my experience get one or two once in a while but the timeout mechanism will sort that out. Perhaps utilise a heart beat mechanism?

Comment: @EdHeal I do not know about heart beat mechanism yet. I wanted to implement my own keep-alive mechanism by sending empty packets to clients. As far as I know system keep-alive timeout on linux is two hours which is way to much and is a system-wide setting which can be overwritten by other applications if I change it to e.g. one minute.

Comment: @Kolunya - But why is this a problem for your server in the first place

Comment: @EdHeal as I've already said, my server constantly polls client sockets which keep on connecting and disconnecting incorrectly _VERY_ often which hits my server performance significantly, since it keeps on polling dead sockets which makes no sense. Is my English so bad that it's not understandable what I am trying to say?

Comment: @kolunya - So lots of clients have not closed down properly. i.e computers crashing, routers crashing etc.

Comment: @EdHeal `select`ing dead sockets makes zero sense too.

Comment: Just read the documentation on `select`. You zero the FD set. Add the ones interested. Prune if necessary/read/write.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm interested in each socket which didn't disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know system keep-alive timeout on linux is two hours which
>   is way to much and is a system-wide setting which can be overwritten
>   by other applications if I change it to e.g. one minute. –  Kolyunya

There you can also set keepalive options per socket.

```
int true = 1;
int idle = 60;
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_KEEPALIVE,  &true, sizeof true) < 0
 || setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE,  &idle, sizeof idle) < 0
 || setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &true, sizeof true) < 0   /* 1 s */
   ) perror("setsockopt");
```